# Need IBM Websphere jax ws webservices.xml and web.xml file

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws

I don't have the sample webservices.xml and web.xml file. Can some one help by providing a complete example? I'm using Web Sphere JAX-WS implementation. WAS 7.x version. JDK 1.6.

I tried setting "UseWSFEP61ScanPolicy: true" in MANIFEST.MF file, for automated annotation scanning (instead of webservices.xml and web.xml file usage), but it is working first time, and after deploying a dynamic patch it doesn' works. The services listed under "services" category of IBM Console is having question mark instead of green arrow. Also some times the services even not listed in "services" category.

I'm using web module version 2.3, so i've to enable automated scanning. I'm not using EJB for web service.

I've decided to use webservices.xml and web.xml due to not much help in annotation scanning. I hope for webservices.xml and web.xml not need to install and reinstall the application EAR in WebSphere. In the case of annotation scanning reinstall is needed.

PLEASE IBM WEB SITE DOESN'T HELP MUCH!!!

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a web.xml I've used.  Since it's "empty", the default rules for mapping annotated webservice classes to URL's apply, approximately,  URL = name of class + "Service".

webservices.xml is not needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>wsfp_hello_svc</display-name>

</web-app>
```

Check SystemOut.log to find the URL of your service, look for something like this:

```
WSWS7037I: The /HelloService URL pattern was configured for the example.HelloDelegate servlet
```

If you don't like the default mappings, then you can map your webservice class to a different URL in web.xml just like you would do with a servlet.